# Legenda automática Excel (séries vazias)

Tags: microsoft-excel, gráfico-de-dispersão

Em minha planilha tenho um gráfico que recebe atualmente 46 séries.

Todas as séries estão atreladas a banco de dados que dependem de uma única variável, dessa forma ao escolher a variável algumas das sérias retornam #N/D, eu precisaria se possível esconder as séries no campo legenda que não possuem dados. Na figura baixo por exemplo apenas as séries 19 e 22 deveriam estar na legenda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu mudei para um gráfico de linhas, mas continua o mesmo problema também.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi via VBA

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 39").Activate

Dim cht    As Chart
Dim ser    As Series
Dim i, j     As String
Dim wshtA           As Worksheet
Dim EGCD   As Double

    'Formata a séries e cria o rótulos para cada série
    For i = 1 To 46
    Set ser = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i)
    If i = 1 Then
    Else
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = False
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Select
        With Selection.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoFalse
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        End With
        Selection.MarkerSize = 15
        Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        ser.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).ApplyDataLabels
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).DataLabels.Select
        Selection.ShowSeriesName = True
        Selection.ShowValue = False
        Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).HasLeaderLines = False
    End If
Next i

'Filtra as séries que contém "Série Vazia" no título
For i = 1 To 46
    Set ser = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i)
    With ser.Format.Line
        If ser.Name = "Série Vazia" Then
            ser.IsFiltered = True
        Else
            ser.IsFiltered = False
        End If
    End With
Next i
```